# Which scripture contains the famous Ganesha Sloka "Vakratunda Mahakaya..."?

Tags: scripture, ganesha, puja, shloka

The [following](http://greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_ganesha-vakratunda_mahakaya.php) Sloka(in bold ) is probably the most popular among all Ganapaty Slokas

> **"Vakratunda Mahaakaaya Surya Koti Samaprabha**
>   **Nirvighnam Kuru Me Deva sarva Karyesu Sarvada".**
>
> Meaning:O Lord Ganesha, of curved trunk, large body and with the Brilliance of a Million Suns, please make all my works free from obstacles, always.

Question-Which scripture contains this Shloka?

Comment: @AnilKumar If its a Vedic hymn can you say which part of Vedas contains this verse?.You can post as an answer.

Comment: I feel it may be the Mudgal Purana though I am not able to confirm since i haven't got my hands on the text till now. But it appears to be the first text that mentions the VAKRATUNDA roop of Lord Ganesh - Check this - [The 32 incarnations of Ganesh from Mudgal Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mudgala_Purana#The_Thirty_Two_incarnations_of_Ganesha) so the probability is high.

Answer (score 14):

I found the Vakratunda incarnation in Mudgal Brahmana but not the mantra. The closest I could come to this mantra is the following line from the Mahaganapati Shastranam Stotra from the Rudrayamala Tantra that contains the first sentence:

[image: Verse 99]

> vakratuṇḍo mahākāyaḥ koṭisūryasamaprabhaḥ । 
>   ekadaṃṣṭraḥ kṛṣṇapiṅgo vikaṭo dhūmravarṇakaḥ ॥ 99॥

Here's the link to the text - [mahAgaNapatisahasranAmastotra](http://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_ganesha/mahAgaNapatisahasranAmastotra.html?lang=sa). The entire hymn I couldn't find anywhere so this is the closest I could get.

Comment: Good amount of research.

Comment: Thanks @RakeshJoshi yes this one was quite tough to find!

Comment: 'The entire hymn I couldn't find anywhere so this is the closest.' should be rephrased to 'The entire hymn I couldn't find anywhere and this is the closest I could find.' I don't think you went through the entirety of Hindu scriptures available currently in order to reach the decision right? Please do state if that's the case :)

Comment: @user1952500 well I am sure that's impossible for anyone to do but I did check all Ganpati related scriptures especially the ones that feature the word 'Vakratunda' :)

Comment: Agreed. Hence the comment. Your note above says it is the closest, but you mean it is the closest _that you could find_.

Comment: Also note that in the other two line hymn with 'avighnam', there should be no visarga in the first line since it's referring to Ganesha in the sambodhana prathama vibhakti. So it's not exactly the same first line here.

Comment: @user1952500 yes but now that you have pout so much stress on it I am curious to know if the entire verse does exist anywhere in its entirety in any scripture. The second line of the mantra - 'nirvighnam kuru me dev' could actually be a vandana or a prayer added to the first line of this verse.

Comment: It's subtly different in the first line but it could be a ripoff off (or this could be a ripoff of that).

Comment: I searched over the doc, Gaṇapati sahasranāma is present in 31st paṭala of Rudrayāmalatantra's Devīrahasyam https://archive.org/details/RudraYamaloktaShriDeviReshyamKapildevaNarayana/page/n315/mode/2up?view=theater